# Given a sequence of integers, would applying AES encryption to the sequence produce a unique set of strings?

Tags: encryption, aes

Let us say that we take a sequence of the integers from `a` to `a+n-1`: `(a, a+1, a+2, a+n-1)`, where `a` and `n` are picked arbitrarily and have no lower or upper bounds on either, except that `a < n`, and we apply AES encryption to that sequence, one element at a time, utilizing the same key for each element in the sequence..

Assumption is that we encode the resulting ciphered values as `Base64` or some other encoding to produce strings.

Would the resulting set of encrypted strings have *any*, irrespective of how infinitesimally small, chance for collisions?

Comment: Encryption preserves all the information in the source. It just messes it up a lot. so no chance of collisions. There maybe 'weaknesses' in the 'messing up' processes but they will still be unique .

Comment: I think this should be an actual answer. Can you provide proof of this in your answer as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encryption is reversible. Therefore it has to be free of collisions. For every AES input block, there is a unique output, forming a "code book," with all the vulnerabilities that implies.